# Debugger problem regarding to how to see all the value in the dynamic array in c++

Tags: c++, debugging

I need to understand the other people's code by debugging through all the code, in the meantime, I can't change or add any code. The one major problem comes up. That is When I want to see the all the value in a dynamic array by adding it to Watch, it would not give me what I expect to. I am only able to see first value of the them. Such as:

[image]

In addition, when I add it to Watch, it would show no operator "[]" matches these operands.

How can i address this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can follow this link, it shows you how to use feature called the “size specifier”to display the array elements:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/habibh/2009/06/05/size-specifier-how-to-display-a-cc-pointer-as-an-array-in-the-visual-studio-debugger/

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to see the value in the boost::ptr_vector during debugging

Comment: Check out VS's .natvis debugging extensions. They can really help debugging. Also see this github about visualizers for boost containers. https://github.com/KindDragon/CPPDebuggerVisualizers/blob/master/VS2015/Visualizers/boost_PointerContainerLibrary.natvis